# How to make multi-threaded image upload in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a collection of URL addresses of images in a file
I read every url and send to

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve (image_src, FileName)
```

but the download ends after 5-10 images and I get the error `<urlopen error [WinError 10060]`

I think that threads will solve this problem, but I don’t know how to do it

Comment: what's the full error?

Comment: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] The attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful, because the required response was not received from another computer in the required time, or an already established connection was disconnected due to an incorrect response from an already connected computer>

Comment: Aren't you hitting download limits of the portal?